# How do you search for tabs in the linux command less?

Tags: linux, less

How do you search for tabs in the linux command less?

I've tried `/\t` but that only seems to search for the character `t`.

Answer (score 30):

At the risk of suggesting the obvious:

<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>/</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for tabs using `/^I` (where ^I is <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>).